# Used Poweregde 2950 worth buying to replace existing Poweredge 840

Tags: untagged

I have a client that has a Dell PowerEdge 840, E2160 1.8GHz, 4G RAM, 2x 250G HD, running SBS 2003 with Exchange and 15 users. There is a database application using SQL running on the server as well. The server is noticeably slow. I have another client who moved away from a server to a NAS and wants to sell the server. It's a Dell Poweredge 2950, E5430 Quad-Core 2.66Ghz, 4G RAM, 3x 1T HD, with SBS 2003 and Exchange. It was purchased in 2008 and the asking price is $1000. Would you recommend purchasing the used server or a new one to replace the Poweredge 840?

Comment: "What to buy" is off topic for SF...  But PowerEdge 2950s have reached Dell support's EOL.  You would have to look elsewhere for hardware support should you select the 2950.  Buy new.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is their only server.  If it goes down they are probably dead in the water.  In situations like that I would always recommend buying new hardware with enterprise level support (meaning, parts are supplied and guaranteed in stock by the OEM). Waiting several days for refurb parts to arrive off ebay is never fun.

Comment: Unless you spend extra on a HA warranty nobody guarantees anything to be in stock...I get this problem all the time with my customers with Dell.